# Is it befitting to use "I would agree" in a formal writing?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

Can we start off a paragraph with "I would agree" when we want to establish our perspective on a subject in a formal and academic writing? What is the difference between "I agree" and "I would agree"?

Example:

Question: "When on a date, the man should always pay. Do you agree or disagree? Explain."

Answer: "I would agree. I believe ..."

Comment: "I would agree" indicates that you have been asked a hypothetical question, or that what follows is conditional on something, but the question quoted is clear: "Do you agree or disagree?" So if you begin with "I would agree" that could show that your reasoning will follow a line which makes it hard for you to decide one way or the other.

Comment: ... The other usage is the ultra-polite but _very_ formal one. 'I would agree' just equals 'I agree', but something you'd expect from Harry Hart (Kingsman) or Noel Coward.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @Greybeard why not?

Comment: *I would **tend** to agree* is an even more polite, and even less committed, phrasing than just *I would agree*.

Comment: *I would agree* can be used to temper one's own opinion in the context of a larger argument: "While I would agree that the protesters deserve to be heard, I cannot join myself to them for fear of the mob mentality that too often prevails." In the context of a straightforward answer, *I agree* is preferable by far.